# How to use async:false in angular js 1.6, so that java script next line execution get block until $http completed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, I am using angularjs 1.6, calling `$http` to initialize an array, and using that array after 1000 line of code in an angularjs controller, but some strange thing is happening every time. Sometimes I get array initialized properly and sometimes I don't.

Basically, I would like to call JavaScript code in certain order, like line1, line2, line3 etc, here line1 may call `$http`, line2 may call some function line3 again `$http`,

Even I have tried using

```
$http( {  method:'POST',
          url:'/getData',
          async:false
        })
```

But It's not holding execution JavaScript, instead, next line of code gets executed.
Is there any way to control this, so  that I can execute the JavaScript code in the same order in the same way I have written,

Comment: Unlike older languages where I/O operations block code execution, the JavaScript engine uses non-blocking I/O operations where one furnishes a function that is executed when the operation completes. Instead of trying to get the AngularJS to behave like an old-fashioned language, learn how to work with non-blocking I/O. The $http service returns a promise. Learn how to use those promises to [chain](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q#chaining-promises) operations.

Comment: Looks like you're chaining a lot of promises. async/await is the perfect fit and the modern way of solving your problem. Please avoid callback hell and spaghetti code like advised above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in many case moving to "none asynchrone" call is a bad idea. You don't know how long this call will take, and during this time you block the UI event loop, so nothing more is working and your website will be totaly stuck during this time, which is pretty a bad thing.

Depend of what you are using (ecma script / javascript) but **async function** seem to be what you are looking for : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/async_function

Exemple :

```
async function myFunction(){
    var data = await $http.get(...);
    await $http.post(..);
    return "my data";
}
```

Everything in this function will be execute in the order it's define thanks to the keyword **await** but it's still asynchrone, the whole function will return a Promise.

```
myFunction().then(function(myData) {
   console.log("End of the asynchrone function " + myData);
});
```

Comment: The ES6 `await` is not integrated with the AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: Yes you can have some refresh problem which can be corrected with $scope.apply,  it's not the best thing, but at least the code could be easier to read than chaining at lot of promise since if controller already have 1k line... perhaps you should also dispatch some code in a service to simplify your controller and certainly correct some bug

Comment: Yes, async/await works in AngularJS. It's javascript, it doesn't need to be integrated into a framework.

Answer (score 0):

xrobert35's answer worked for me,
below is my angularjs function which worked in synchronous way.

example:

```
$scope.Filter = async function (buid) {
              
        var post = await $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "abc.aspx/getdata",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { year: $("#ddl_year option:selected").val() },
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            async: false
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.d != null && response.data.d.length > 0) {
                $("#loader").hide();
                $scope.globaldata = "";
                var data = JSON.parse(response.data.d);
                $scope.globaldata = data;
            }
            else {
                $("#loader").hide();
                $scope.Messagegrid = "Record does not exists";
            }
        });
}
```